# Integrability of a "shuffled" function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I was wondering about this question, but I simply don't have the tools to tackle it.

Suppose we have some function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is monotonic at least in some interval $(a,b)$. Now consider a second function $g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x) \ \forall \ x \in (a,b)$, but there exists a single $y \neq x \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) = g(y)$. In other words, the image of $g$ coincides with the image of $f$ for the subset $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, but $f(x)$ never maps to the same element as $g(x)$, so $g$ is a "shuffling" of $f$, in a sense, with no fixed points.

Under the conditions above:

1. Can we establish some $g$, by proof or example, such that it is not Riemann and/or Lebesgue integrable in the interval $(a,b)$? I suspect that the answer is yes for the Riemann case. No clue for the Lebesgue case.
2. If $g$ is integrable, does
   $$
   \int_a^b f(x)\,\mathbb{d}x = \int_a^b g(x)\,\mathbb{d}x
   $$
   always follows?

Comment: One practical example where 2 is true is the [symmetric decreasing rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_decreasing_rearrangement). Generally speaking though, there is no continuous analogue of the idea of a permutation of an absolutely convergent series (what you call a "shuffling") - continuous "shufflings" are just reparametrizations, which, as MartinArgerami's example demonstrates, can pretty much arbitrarily deform the original function. I suppose piecewise continuous reparametrizations with constant derivative $\pm1$ would also preserve the integral though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get examples with $g$ non-measurable, which precludes it from being integrable. For instance take $(a,b)=(0,1)$, and $f(x)=x$. Let $E\subset(0,1)$ be any uncountable non-measurable set and $h:E\to (0,1)$ a bijection. Then take
$$
g(x)=h(x)\,1_E. 
$$
Then $g$ is not measurable because $g^{-1}(0,1)=E$, while $g(0,1)=(0,1)$. One can easily tweak $h$ so that $g$ agrees with $f$ at some points.

The second condition fails very easily. An integral takes into account where the function takes its values. Again take $f(x)=x$, and $g(x)=2(x-x^2)$. Then
$$
\int_0^1f=\frac12\,\qquad\qquad\int_0^1 g=\frac13.
$$
We have $f(1/2)=g(1/2)$.

Comment: I think your integrals should be on $(0, 1/2)$, since this is the interval over which $g$ is a "reordering" of $f$ (according to OP's definition).

Comment: As far as I see, OP considers only one interval $(a,b)$. Properly, the functions should be $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, which is easily achieved by defining them as $0$ outside of $(0,1)$.